# How to select columns where some columns contain certain data select all columns with same another column

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have database as this...

```
$db = [
['a' => 1, 'b'=> 2  ],
['a' => 1, 'b'=> 12 ],
['a' => 2, 'b'=> 2  ],
['a' => 3, 'b'=> 12 ],
['a' => 4, 'b'=> 2  ],
['a' => 4, 'b'=> 12 ],
['a' => 4, 'b'=> 4  ],
    ];
```

How to correctly write a where statement, to see all `a` where one of them have `b=4`or containing ONLY `b=12` ?

```
WHERE
```

Does apply only for one row as far as I know. I think this is like three times parsing database for each statement, but I don't worry about performance this time.

EDIT: It's common a's elements of WHERE 'b=12' and WHERE 1=1

Answer (score 0):

do you mean getting column b that have value 4 or 12?
maybe u can use this
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE b IN (4,12);`

Comment: I want to see all a=4 or a=3 in this example.

Comment: as based on your question you want to get value b=4 or 12 and only a that have value 4 or 3, is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a IN ( SELECT a FROM table WHERE b=4);
```

Second one seems to be

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a NOT IN ( SELECT a FROM table WHERE b != 12) AND b = 12;
```